# Wierd Behavior, identical code fails in one place, works in main

Tags: c++, sorting

I got this wierd problem trying to use std::sort. I followed the general guides around the web, and after failing alot, produced this simple MCVE:

comparator function:

```
bool comp(int i, int j)
{
    return (i<j);
}
```

just below we got main:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(rand() %10);
        std::cout<<vec[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),comp);
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<vec[i]<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

This code works just fine, it does exactly what you'd expect it to do.

When, however, I place the exact same code in my class, and then try to compile, the compiler starts moaning about "unresolved overloaded function type".

Transfered to my theoretical class evalengine, it looks like this:

```
bool evalengine::comp(int i, int j)
{
    return (i<j);
}


vector<int> evalengine::evaluateHand()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(rand() %10);
        std::cout<<vec[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),comp);
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<vec[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Like my actual code, it says the same thing, "unresolved overloaded function types".

But why? The code is identical. The only difference is that it's moved from my main.cpp into my evalengine.cpp, it's moved into a class scope, but that shouldn't matter right? The only other difference, if it is worth noting, is that I now ofcourse have to deal with headers, I tried specifying the namespace when pointing to the function comp, IE evalengine::comp instead of just comp, had no effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just plain `comp` is not the function you intend to give to `sort`.  Member functions should be qualified with the class name:  `evalengine::comp`.

Hope you thought about making `comp` a static function - otherwise you'll need to do that, too.

Actually, you may not need this `comp`, since the standard library contains just this function: [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).  A more C++ish way to sort the vector would be:

```
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec), std::less<int>());
```

It's a very good idea to learn what's available in the standard library!

Comment: Ok, that worked. But why? I didn't have to specify anything static in main.cpp.

Nor do I have to specify the local namespace, just calling comp works fine, after I made it static ofcourse.

Comment: Because your new `comp` is a _member_ function.  It's actually not a very good idea to make it a member function unless it's result depends on the current state of the object.  It's perfectly valid to keep `comp` a free function (inside an anonymous namespace), or better still, use `std::less()` which does exactly the same as your `comp`!

Comment: std::sort won't take a member function for the compare function. You can use a lambda function or a function operator (functor) to get something like a member function.